Trying to imitate a WCF netpipe host and tap raw messages
For study purpose, I am trying to imitate a WCF pipe service host.
I have the following trivial Service definition
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPipeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PipeIn(string data);
}

And a client console app which consumes it via net pipes (DotNet 8 SDK)
 string URI = "net.pipe://localhost/Pipe";
 var cf = new ChannelFactory<IPipeService>(
     new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None),
     new EndpointAddress(URI));

 cf.Open();
 IPipeService proxy = cf.CreateChannel();

 proxy.PipeIn("Hello");

I am trying to tap the raw message, so I have a server-side process that is running this trivial 2 line code:
var pipeIn = new NamedPipeServerStream("net.pipe://localhost/Pipe", PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None);
pipeIn.WaitForConnectionAsync(token);

The problem is that pipeIn.WaitForConnectionAsync() waits forever, and on the client side, I am getting this error thrown immediately when proxy.PipeIn() is called:
There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/Pipe that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I tried to debug the client code, dug into the WCF guts, but to no avail. I couldn't find the code which is doing the actual "weight lifting", and I suspect that since the client proxy is auto generated, the VS22 debugger is unable to properly debug it.
What am I missing?
What am I missing?

There's a problem with your address, here's a solution:
The URL address of your server port cannot contain the interface address.
Such as:
Service
var baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost");

 using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PipeService), baseAddress))
 {
     var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
     host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPipeService), binding, "PipeService");

     host.Open();

     Console.WriteLine("Host run");
     Console.ReadLine();
 }

Client:
string URI = "net.pipe://localhost/PipeService";
 var cf = new ChannelFactory<IPipeService>(
     new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None),
     new EndpointAddress(URI));

 IPipeService proxy = cf.CreateChannel();
 proxy.PipeIn("Hello");
 Console.ReadLine();


If your server URL address matches the client's, you'll get an error:


I am actually trying to imitate the ServiceHost by myself (in DotNet 8, for study purposes), so I'm wondering what is in fact the actual pipe name/endpoint in the server side? shouldn't it match the client's pipe name?

Actually, it's the same, you look at the code on the server. It has an AddServiceEndpoint, which you can understand by looking at its source code. He'll add that address.

I debugged and I saw that the server also exposes the end point "net.pipe://localhost/PipeService", so how can it be that NamedPipeServerStream above didn't accept the connection?

For some reason I can't debug the critical code, probably since it's generated. I just can't step into the call. So I tried different approach. I used legacy dotnet 4.8.1 framework to create a named pipe service endpoint, and then I used powershell to print out all the named pipes in the system. Amazingly, there was named pipe in the name of net.pipe://localhost/PipeService.

Apparently, even though the WCF service endpoint exposed as "net.pipe://localhost/Pipe" (in this case), the actual underlying named-pipe name is randomized. The mapping from the public endpoint address to the actual randomized pipe name is kept in a shared memory area, so trying to tap the endpoint with NamedPipeServerStream or NamedPipeClientStream, won't work.
